# Setting Dependency Injection for ILogger<UserService> without implementing all ILogger interface methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, dependency-injection

I have created an `ASP.NET Core` application and I have a problem with the `Dependency Injection` (DI) setting for `ILogger<UserService>`. I want to use logging in the `UserService` class, but I don't want to implement all the methods of the `ILogger` interface. My goal is to separate the logging functionality from the `UserService` class. Just use `ILogger` interface for logging.

I tried registering the service in `Program.cs` as follows:

`builder.Services.AddScoped<ILogger<UserService>, UserServiceLogger>();`

**UserService class:**

```
public class UserService : ILogger<UserService>
    {
        public readonly ILogger<UserRepository>? _logger;

        public UserService(ILogger<UserRepository>? logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public bool CheckCredentials(string email, string password)
        {

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(email) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            {
                _logger?.LogError(LogMessage.UserNotFound);

                throw new CredentialsAreEmpty();
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

I was thinking to create `UserLoggingService` and implement `ILogger<UserService>` there.

is this the correct procedure or can it be done differently and better?

Comment: Shouldn't `ILogger<UserRepository>? _logger` be `ILogger<UserService>`?

What makes you think you have to implement all the methods of `ILogger`? 
Only a class that implements the `ILogger` interface would have to do that and that not what you're here.

`builder.Services.AddScoped<ILogger<UserService>, UserServiceLogger>();`
It's not necessary to register the ILogger.

Comment: Why does `UserService` _implement_ `ILogger<UserService>`? That's not how that works. Remove that.

Comment: You are also logging the wrong message. If input validation fails, you have invaild input, you did not _not find_ a user.

Answer (score 0):

For answer your question : It is quite the way to use the ILogger mechanism, you just don't need to implement ILogger.
The following class signature is enough.

```
    public class UserService
    {
    }
```

And the registration of all ILogger is done by the framework.
You don't need `CSharp builder.Services.AddScoped<ILogger<UserService>, UserServiceLogger>();`
Then for logging what Ilogger needs to log you can use :

- The built-in log system [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#bilp)

  --> Good choice for "Windows" logging (eventViewer and console)
- Thrid-party library [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#third-party-logging-providers).

  --> Heavier to install but customizable (log in file ,database, kafka event, email, ...)

They both furnish implementation for the Ilogger interface.
I personally use Nlog [Implementation example](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-6), which is quite simple to use and configure, it is thread safe (for 99% of its usage) and compatible with multi-targets.

For small app, with no performance required your still can create, implement and inject your own interface with few methods (writing in a file or a database for example).